# Как искать значение во вложенных объектах?

Tags: javascript

Возьмем такой объект, для примера:

```
{a: {b: {message: 1, d: {message: 2}}}};
```

Как найти все `message` без рекурсии или с ее хвостовой оптимизацией.

Объекты могут быть очень большими, больше, чем в примере, есть риск "словить" переполнение стека.
А оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии корректно имплементировать не смог.

**Update 1:**

```
function objectScale() {
    let scaled = {message: 'test'};

    for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
        scaled = {scaled, message: '1'};
    }

    return scaled;
}

const object = objectScale();
```

Как найти все `message` в `object`? Скажем, добавить их в массив?

**Update 2:**

Пример результата:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] (получен от array.push(message), где message - 1)
```

Comment: и сколько же у вас там предполагается уровней вложенности, что боитесь переполнения стека?

Comment: что хотите на выходе получить?

Comment: @teran, затрудняюсь ответить. Тысячи точно... Как решить задачу (обновил пример)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, обновил. вопрос, хочу найти все сообщения из объекта, что в примере. (Update 1)

Comment: в таком случае проще регуляркой по строковому представлению объекта))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это если не считать время для перевода объекта в строку :-)

Comment: @Grundy `md5(obj)`  :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в хэше тяжело найти значения отдельных полей :-)

Comment: @Grundy это была шутка)

Comment: @Lasna1, добавь в вопрос пример результата, для твоего кода.

Comment: @Grundy, обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект можно рассматривать в качестве графа: корнем является сам объект, а ветвями - свойства.

Таким образом задача сводится к обходу графа в глубину либо в ширину.

Для этого достаточно хранить все доступные ветки в массиве и в цикле постепенно исключать их, добавляя при этом дочерние ветки.

Для более удобной работы можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), позволяющий получить список ключей и их значений.

```js
function objectScale() {
  let scaled = {
    message: 'test'
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    scaled = {
      scaled,
      message: 'test' + (i + 1)
    };
  }

  return scaled;
}

const object = objectScale();

function find(o, findkey) {
  var entries = Object.entries(o); // получаем дочерние узлы
  var result = [];
  while (entries.length) { // пока есть непроверенные узлы
    var [key, val] = entries.pop(); // берем один узел
    if (key == findkey) result.push(val); // если ключ соответствует искомому - добавляем результат

    // если значение является объектом
    if (val != null && typeof val == 'object') entries.push(...Object.entries(val)); // добавляем его дочерние узлы в список непроверенных
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(find(object, 'message'))
```

Comment: корни и ветви таки у дерева, а у графа вершины и ребра.

Comment: @teran, ага, у меня все смешалось пока писал :):):)

Comment: применительно к объекту граф получится если имеются какие-то рекурсивные связи между объектами дочерними, тогда и бесконечный цикл обхода можно получать, если не помечать вершины как посещенные

Comment: @teran, ну не. граф он и так есть. Наличие или отсутствие циклов не делает из графа не граф

Comment: из дерева зато граф делает )

Comment: @teran, ну, дерево и без циклов графом является :-)

Comment: теперь у меня смешалось :D короче наличие циклов сделает алгоритм бесконечным без отметок посещенных вершин.

Comment: @teran, да, сделает, и есть такие объекты есть надо как-то помечать :) но в данном случае без этого работает и так